# Do any good topolect maps exist for Chinese?

Tags: topolect

I've been rummaging through English dialect maps. Here's an example of one on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/tweetolectology/status/1202497584826204161):

> [image: yoyo]

And an American one for good measure:

> [image: lololo]

Do any good topolect maps exist for Chinese?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you were looking for, but there is a book that does this kind of study [中国语言地图集](https://book.douban.com/series/32059).

You can refer to [知乎](https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/45091588) for some examples.